# Is it possible to undo close tab in Matlab's editor?

Tags: matlab

Many web browsers allow to undo close tab:

[image]

Is it possible to undo close tab in Matlab's editor?

I use R2014a on Windows 7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't officially supported in MATLAB, but with reference to [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/recovering-previous-editor-state), there is a workaround.

MATLAB stores its Desktop windows state in a file called `MATLABDesktop.xml` that is located in the user’s `prefdir` (preference directory) folder. You can echo where this is in MATLAB by simply typing in `prefdir` in the Command Prompt and pushing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.  As you are also using Windows, you can also do this to open up the folder within MATLAB:

```
winopen(prefdir);
```

This should open up a new Windows Explorer window that will directly bring you to the `prefdir` folder.

This file includes information about the position and state of every Desktop window. Since the editor files are considered Desktop documents, they are also included in this file.  As such, when you close the editor, these documents are simply removed from the `MATLABDesktop.xml` file.

It turns out that MATLAB automatically stores a backup version of this file in another file called `MATLABDesktop.xml.prev`, in the same `prefdir` folder.  I'm also using MATLAB R2014a in Windows 7 and I have double-checked to see if these files are also on my system and they are!

So before doing anything else, close MATLAB, delete the latest `MATLABDesktop.xml` file, replace it with a copy of the `MATLABDesktop.xml.prev` file, renaming it to `MATLABDesktop.xml`.  After, restart MATLAB and the editor should reopen with your previous tabs.

Comment: I'm always impressed by knowledge about this kind of undocumented things. +1

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code. It extracts the file names from `MATLABDesktop.xml.prev`

```
%parse XML file
xmlFiles    = xmlread([prefdir filesep 'MATLABDesktop.xml.prev']);
%Retrieve the "clients"
FileNodes   = xmlFiles.getElementsByTagName('Client');
%get the length of the FileNodes
nrFiles     = FileNodes.getLength;
%initialize Files
Files       = cell(nrFiles,1);
%initialize isFile
isFile      = zeros(nrFiles,1);
%Iterate over all Elements and check if it is a file.
for iNode = 0:nrFiles-1 % Java indexing.
    %Files
    Files{iNode+1} = char(FileNodes.item(iNode).getAttribute('Title'));
    %check if the "client" is a file:
    isFile(iNode+1) = exist(Files{iNode+1},'file') == 2 && ~(strcmp(Files{iNode+1},'Workspace'));
end
%remove the other files:
MyFiles = Files(find(isFile));
%open the files in the editor:
edit(MyFiles{:});
```

From [mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/466648-how-to-reopen-matlab-scripts-function-when-the-editor-was-accidentally-closed)